# how to add a new row using react-table v7

Tags: reactjs, react-table-v7

i am using react-table v7. What i want to achieve is to add a new row below a row when a button is clicked. Like jquery datatables https://datatables.net/ when name is clicked a new row is added into the table, how can i do the same with react-table v7.